# Адаптация текста

Tags: html, css

подскажите, пожалуйста, как адаптировать заголовок ? [![фото

```
h1{
```

font-size:20vw;
}

@media{font-size:10vw;
[image: текст не в центре фото]

][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POnhZ.jpg)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POnhZ.jpg)

Comment: Слышали когда-нибудь о `@media screen`?

Comment: @ΝNL993 Судя по коду слышала, но не дочитала, как вообще его использовать. На всякий случай ссылочку надо оставить: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/@media

Comment: Спасибо, я уже сделала адаптив текста, нужно было подольше покопаться